# Can I rename DFs based on a lookup table in list format?

Tags: r

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
names_lookup <- list(
  'mpg' = 'miles_per_gallon',
  'cyl' = 'cylinder'
)
```

I know how to rename columns manually with dplyr::rename

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% rename(miles_per_gallon = mpg, cylinder = cyl)
```

I wouldlike to know, is there a way I can use my list, 'names_lookup' to rename columns intead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we need the key/values switched in the `list`

```
names_lookup <- list('miles_per_gallon' = 'mpg', 'cylinder' = 'cyl')
```

and then do an evaluation with `!!!`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
       rename(!!! names_lookup)
```

-checking

```
names(mtcars1)
#[1] "miles_per_gallon" "cylinder"         "disp"             "hp"               "drat"             "wt"              
#[7] "qsec"             "vs"               "am"               "gear"             "carb"            names(mtcars)
#[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

---

Or another option is `rename_at`

```
mtcars %>% 
     rename_at(vars(unlist(names_lookup)), ~ names(names_lookup))
```

---

If some column names are not present in the dataset, we can subset the `list` based on the occurrence of values `%in%` the column names

```
names_lookup$hello <- 'Hello'
i1 <- unlist(names_lookup) %in% names(mtcars)
names_lookup_sub <- names_lookup[i1]

mtcars %>% 
 rename_at(vars(unlist(names_lookup_sub)), 
             ~ names(names_lookup_sub))
```

Or with `rename`

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
       rename(!!! names_lookup[i1])
```

Comment: Beautiful. What exactly is `!!!` doing here in Renglish?

Comment: @DougFir It is a bang-bang operator.  According to documentation `The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `match` to find out column index to replace the names.

```
names(mtcars)[match(names(names_lookup),names(mtcars))] <- unlist(names_lookup)
names(mtcars)
# [1] "miles_per_gallon" "cylinder"         "disp"             "hp"              
# [5] "drat"             "wt"               "qsec"             "vs"              
# [9] "am"               "gear"             "carb"
```